# XSLT:How to check if a specific string is present in string of tags separated by delimiter ","

Tags: xslt

i,
i am new to xml/xslt.
Need to prepare  template which checks the value of a tag 123,447,786,780 and returns true if 447 exists in the string and false if not

I am trying below piece of code but somehow its not working

```
   <xsl:template name="tokenize"> 
  <xsl:Param name="text"/> 
  <xsl:Param name="delimiter" select="','"/> 
   <xsl:choose> 
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $delimiter)"> 
               <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $delimiter)">true</xsl:when> 
                               <xsl:-Otherwise>false</xsl:-Otherwise> 
         </xsl:choose> 
      </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Need to prepare template which checks the value of a tag
>   123,447,786,780 and returns true if 447 exists in the string and false
>   if not

You don't need a template for this, only a simple XPath expression:

```
contains(concat(',', $yourstring, ','), ',447,')
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your original XML structure, but suppose to have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Test.xsl"?>

<RootNode>
    <SampleNode Value="123,456,789" />
    <SampleNode Value="123,447,789" />
    <SampleNode Value="447,123,789" />
    <SampleNode Value="123,456,447" />
    <SampleNode Value="123,44476,789" />
</RootNode>
```

The following XSLT transformation works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">

    <xsl:template match="RootNode">
        <html>
            <body>
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="SampleNode" />
                </ul>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SampleNode">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Value" /> contains '447':
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(concat(',', @Value, ','), ',447,')">
                    <strong>Yes</strong>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    No
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With something like this you are able to extract what you want, I think. Basically it is an XPath expression.

Comment: Your test will return a false positive when the string is "123,9447,789" or "123,4475,789" or "123,94475,789".

Comment: You are perfectly right! Thanks for pointing it out! The XPath expression from your post is better. I modify my code sample.